# HTML5 store form data to csv file

Tags: html

I have a html5 form over two pages and want to store the user input in a csv file.
Is there any other way then php to save this data to a csv file??

Comment: Yes, there are countless ways. Is your HTML5 form served from a server that can accept the response? Or is your user just going to have the .html file on their desktop and run it locally?

Comment: Save it where? Locally? On the server?

Comment: The form is on a server and the csv file should be saved on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={YOURFILENAME}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

foreach($csvData as $line){
    foreach($line as $val){
        echo '"'.$val.'";';
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

You just need to write each cell, separated by semicolon (;) or comma (,).

$csvData is an array (form) containing array (line) containing value (cell).

These headers force download when the user click on the php file url.

Comment: Could you explain me this please?

Comment: It will be hard to explain, obviously you need to learn from the beginning.
First, why would you save data in csv and not in database ?
If you don't know php i think you should try to save your form into MySQL, then use the code i gave you to generate a csv from database information.

You must learn PHP (or another server side language). HTML is useless without a real language.